# How do I add a space when pressing the return button on a UITextfield in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I have this text field where the user can insert text in it and I want to automatically press the space bar button when the return button is pressed. Is there anyway to be able to do that?

```
//when user presses return the keyboard will dismiss and automatically add a space

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ searchTextField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    searchTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
searchTextField.text! += " " 
searchTextField.resignFirstResponder()
```

Comment: It adds a space but deletes the text that I entered.

Answer (score 1):

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.text = "\(textField.text ?? "")_" //replace underscore with space
    return true
}
```

Concat the space to current text on textfield